# pyplot/matplotlib (damped) oscillation / soundwave graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I've been searching online for hours but can't find a way to make a graph like the picture below, or even the picture itself or the name. But to the point, is there a way to plot this in pyplot? Though anything else that looks like a soundwave will work too. It doesn't matter whether it is continious/repetitive.
[image: graph]

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html
There are multiple examples there with some that look like your picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's just the sum(or difference) of 2 different frequency sine waves

with a relatively prime frequency ratio you can see a regular "beat frequency" envelope at the frequency difference for a longer record

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
W = np.linspace(0., 10.0, num=500)
plt.plot(W, np.sin(W*2*np.pi), 'b')
plt.plot(W, -np.sin(W*1.1*2*np.pi), 'y')
plt.plot(W, np.sin(W*2*np.pi) - np.sin(W*1.1*2*np.pi), 'g')
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is so much simpeler than I thought! Most of the normal sine pyplot examples I found are way more complicated too.